# how to print reverse number pattern triangle in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {              
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = i; k <= 4; k++) {                    
        System.out.print(k+"");
    }                                  
    System.out.println();            
}
```

Current output:

```
   4
  34
 234
1234
```

Desired output:

```
   1
  21
 321
4321
```

What changes are necessary in order for me to get the desired output as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

Let the first loop (i) run from 1 to 4 and the second (j) from 4 to i.
This reverses your output.

Answer (score 1):

You did every thing right, just the last for should have a very minor change:

```
for (int k = 5-i; k >= 1; k--){
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 4; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--){
            System.out.print(k + "");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are incorrect, you can refer the below code with inline comments:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { //iterate from 1 to 4  
    //Loop from i+1 to insert spaces first
    for (int j = i+1; j <= 4; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    //Loop from i to insert the number next to each other
    for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println(); //insert a new line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
{   
  for (int k = i; k <= 4; k++)
   {                    
      System.out.print(" ");
   }  
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
   {
      System.out.print(j);
   }                                
    System.out.println();            
 }
```